# PHP If string contains '+' change it to 'test'?

Tags: php

how might I be able to do this?

I'm familiar with the str operators, but am pretty unsure how might I be able to do this.

Logic test:

```
    If (string.contains == '+') {
string.change("test");
}
```

Basically what it's needed for:

```
it'll be used for a string that contains more then just a + e.g. hello+hello will change into -> hellotesthello
```

Comment: You should provide some examples like 'hello+hello' > 'hellotesthello'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(strpos($string, '+') !== false){
   $string = 'test';
}
```

If you want to change the `+` into `test` you would use

```
$string = str_replace('+', 'test', $string);
```

Comment: For a shorter syntax: `if(strstr($string, '+'))`

Comment: `Note:
If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.`

Comment: @Jessica Hey, Jessica thanks again, will this work in a string that contains more then just a + e.g. hello+hello will change into -> hellotesthello, right?

Comment: That is not what your question described.

Comment: @Jessica Sorry I thought it was clear I'll edit said question.

Comment: @Jessica <?php
$string = $_GET['s'];
if(strpos($string, '+') !== false){
$string = str_replace('+', 'test', $string);
}
echo $string;
?> // Displaying hi+ in the script only echos hi, what's going wrong here?

Comment: Again, your post doesn't say anything about using the URL query string. Look up URL encoding. (+ is a space in a URL) The code I provided is fine. http://ideone.com/GELIWZ

Comment: In the future, I suggest you ask the question using ALL of the details, and provide actual examples, so you're not dragging it out.

Comment: @Jessica Sorry, I didn't realize, I thought it would work with a $_GET request too, how would I get this working? Don't tell me I need to do urlencoding again..

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\+/','test',$string);
```

Comment: Regex is an unnecessary use of resources for something so simple.

Comment: Actually I didnt know that strpos and str_replace are significantly faster.

Comment: No problem..I didn't know `strpos` was faster than `strstr`.